# Windows Server 2016 не открывает свои сайты(проблемы с DNS)

Tags: dns, iis, windows-server

Если я использую публичный DNS от гугл(8.8.8.8) - находясь на сервере, я могу открыть в браузере сайт, который хостит мой сервер(IIS).

Но мне нужно указать DNS 127.0.0.1 - в этом случае я не могу открыть сайт и получаю ошибку ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

DNS имеет статическую айпи

также интересный факт, если в файл hosts записать строку - 127.0.0.1    <название_сайта> - он начнет резолвится!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы прописываете dns 127.0.0.1? У вас на этом сервере установлена роль DNS Server? Или только iis?

Comment: скорее мне НЕ нужно использовать DNS гугла, это было установлено старым сис адм! Роль DNS і IIS на одном сервере

Comment: Тогда на сервере у вас будут доступны только те записи DNS, что вбиты прямо на нем (через DNS Management), т.к. лезть еще куда-то за резолвом имен вы ему запретили. Если он хостит какие-то сайты с внешними именами - придется вписывать их вручную.